# Central limit theorems involving nominal-valued random variables

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, limit-theorems

Suppose $X$ is a random variable taking values in a finite set $\{a_1,\ldots, a_k \}$  and for $i=1,\ldots,k,$ $Y_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } X=a_i, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$

\begin{align}
\text{If } & \operatorname E(\mathbf Y) = \operatorname E\left[ \begin{array}{c} Y_1 \\ \vdots\,\,\, \\ Y_k \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} p_1 \\ \vdots\,\,\, \\ p_k \end{array} \right] \quad \text{(so that $p_1+\cdots+p_k=1$)} \\[12pt] \text{then } & \operatorname{var}(\mathbf Y) = \operatorname{var}\left[ \begin{array}{c} Y_1 \\ \vdots\,\,\, \\ Y_k \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc} \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ \cdots & p_i(1-p_i) & \cdots & -p_ip_j & \cdots \\ & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \cdots & -p_i p_j & \cdots & p_j(1-p_j) & \cdots \\ & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots  \end{array} \right].
\end{align}
This variance is a $k\times k$ matrix of rank $k-1.$

With an infinite sequence of i.i.d. copies of $\mathbf Y,$ we have a central limit theorem saying that the probability distribution of a suitably centered and rescaled sum of the first $n$ copies of $\mathbf Y$ approaches a normal (or "Gaussian") distribution with the $k\times k$ variance above.

Everybody knows that much, but now suppose we have a countably infinite set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$ of values of $X$ with corresponding probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ and we define $\mathbf Y$ similarly.

How should we modify our central limit theorem for that case? Might we have pointwise but not uniform convergence to a limiting distribution? If for each $i,$ the distribution of $W_i$ is limiting distribution of the $i\text{th}$ component, would it still be the case that every linear combination $\sum_i c_iW_i$ with constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients $c_i$ would be normally distributed in the limit? Might some conclusions depend on how fast $\sum_ip_i$ converges to $1\text{?}$ Are there published results?

Comment: "Would it still be the case that every linear combination $\sum_i c_iY_i$ with constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients $c_i$ would be normally distributed in the limit?" -- What limit? The limit of what? Under what conditions?

Comment: @IosifPinelis : Sorry -- that's a sloppily phrased question. I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Now I don't understand what the $W_i$'s are. You have said something about the distribution of $W_i$, but not about $W_i$ itself.

Comment: The distribution is what matters: central limit theorems are about convergence in distribution.

Comment: "If for each $i,$ the distribution of $W_i$ is limiting distribution of the $i\text{th}$ component, would it still be the case that every linear combination $\sum_i c_iW_i$ with constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients $c_i$ would be normally distributed in the limit?" -- (i) "limiting distribution":  under what condition? "the $i\text{th}$ component" of what? (ii) You take linear combinations of the $W_i$'s. So, we need to know the **joint** distribution of the $W_i$'s. (iii) "would be normally distributed in the limit" -- Again, what limit? Under what conditions?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Not yet . . . I've had other things demanding my attention.

Comment: All right. Take your time, and let me know if anything in the answer is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\lp{\mathrm{LP}}\newcommand\ep{\varepsilon}$Let $Y:=\mathbf Y$. Let $Z:=Y-EY.$ Then
$$E\|Z\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j(1-p_j)\le\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j=1<\infty,$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $\ell^2$ norm. So, $Z$ is a zero-mean random vector in the Hilbert space $H:=\ell^2$, with a finite second strong moment and thus with a well-defined covariance operator $T$. Let $G$ be the zero-mean Gaussian random vector over $H$ with covariance operator $T$. Let
$$S_n:=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z^{(i)},$$
where the $Z^{(i)}$'s are independent copies of $Z$. Then it is a well-known  fact that $S_n\to G$ in distribution (as $n\to\infty$) -- see e.g. Theorem 3.6 of [Hoffmann-Jørgensen and Pisier](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2243043).

More refined results are given e.g. in the [paper by Bentkus and Götze](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004400050136); see other papers by Götze for other similar results and further references.

---

In this particular case, the convergence $S_n\to G$ in distribution can be shown more elementarily, as follows. For each natural $m$ and all $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)\in\ell^2$, let
$$\pi_m x:=(x_1,\dots,x_m,0,0,\dots),$$
so that $\pi_m$ is the projector onto "the first $m$ coordinates". Let $\rho_m:=I-\pi_m$, where $I$ is the identity operator, so that $\rho_m$ is the projector onto "the coordinates beyond the first $m$ coordinates". Then, for each natural $m$, by the finite-dimensional central limit theorem (CLT),
$\pi_m S_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_m Z^{(i)}\to\pi_m G$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$, that is,
$$\lp(\pi_m S_n,\pi_m G)\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0, 
\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\lp(U,V)$ is the [Lévy–Prokhorov distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric#Definition) between the (distributions of) random vectors $U$ and $V$.

Next, by the "Pythagoras theorem" for $\ell^2$ and because the $Z^{(i)}$'s are independent copies of $Z$,
$$E\|\rho_m S_n\|^2=E\|\rho_m Z\|^2=\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty p_j(1-p_j)\le\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty p_j=:q_m\to0 \tag{2}\label{2} $$
as $m\to\infty$. Because $S_n$ and $G$ have the same covariance operator, we have
$$E\|\rho_m G\|^2=E\|\rho_m S_n\|^2\le q_m. \tag{3}\label{3}$$
So, for any Borel subset $A$ of $\ell_2$ and any real $\ep$, denoting by $A_\ep$ the $\ep$-neighborhood of $A$ and using Markov's inequality and \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, and \eqref{3}, we have
\begin{align}
&P(S_n\in A) \\ 
&\le P(\pi_m S_n\in A_\ep)+P(\|\rho_m S_n\|\ge\ep) \\ 
&\le P(\pi_m G\in A_{2\ep})+\lp(\pi_m S_n,\pi_m G)+\frac{q_m}{\ep^2} \\ 
&\le P(G\in A_{3\ep})+P(\|\rho_m G\|\ge\ep)+\lp(\pi_m S_n,\pi_m G)+\frac{q_m}{\ep^2} \\ 
&\le P(G\in A_{3\ep})+\frac{q_m}{\ep^2}+\lp(\pi_m S_n,\pi_m G)+\frac{q_m}{\ep^2}.  
\end{align}
Choosing now any $m$ such that $\frac{q_m}{\ep^2}<\ep$, for all large enough $n$ we have $\lp(\pi_m S_n,\pi_m G)<\ep$ and hence
$$P(S_n\in A) \le P(G\in A_{3\ep})+3\ep.$$
Similarly, for all large enough $n$ we have
$$P(G\in A) \le P(S_n\in A_{3\ep})+3\ep.$$
So, $\lp(S_n,G)\le3\ep$ for all large enough $n$. Thus, $S_n\to G$ in distribution. $\quad\Box$